# Meaning of "trovar qualcuno a fare qualcosa"

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> L'ho trovato a lavorare nel giardino. (= I found him working in the garden)

Does this mean that I found him while I was working in the garden or while he was working in the garden?

Comment: Ah, the ambiguity of English! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that you found him, while he was working in the garden. The other meaning could be expressed as

> L'ho trovato lavorando in giardino

or

> L'ho trovato mentre lavoravo in giardino.